# Java EE 7 using Maven gives an error of Unsatisfied Injection Point

Tags: ejb, cdi, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

I am trying to develop a web application on Java EE 7 using maven in GlassFish server. My project give an error and I could not solve it! I have added a screenshot of my whole project. A session bean is in EJB package. And a managed bean in Web package. Injection not working properly. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: How about showing some code ?

Comment: @rangalo : There are no more codes except the code in image.

Comment: most probably you are missing the beans.xml file in resources/META-INF/ do you have it ? An empty one will also do.

Comment: I have created a folder name META-INF in Web package under Web Pages folder. And put a empty bean.xml into the META-INF folder. Not Injection is working. Thanks rangalo.

Comment: I am converting the comment into an answer. Please accept.

Comment: Not only do you need a `META-INF/beans.xml` in your EJB JAR, you also need a `WEB-INF/beans.xml` in your WAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most probably you are missing the beans.xml file in resources/META-INF/ do you have it ? An empty one will also do